# Update one table if condition is met in another

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if this is possible to do in a single query *(I'm trying to write one for quite some time now and nothing comes to my mind)*

I have two tables:

**tickets**

```
+----------+-----+-----------+
| ticketid | win | processed |
+----------+-----+-----------+
|        1 |   0 |         0 |
|        2 |   0 |         0 |
|        3 |   0 |         0 |
+----------+-----+-----------+
```

**playedmatches**

```
+---------+----------+-----+-----------+
| matchid | ticketid | win | processed |
+---------+----------+-----+-----------+
|    1233 |        1 |   1 |         1 |
|    3144 |        1 |   0 |         1 |
|    1334 |        2 |   1 |         1 |
|    4441 |        2 |   1 |         1 |
|    1442 |        3 |   0 |         0 |
|    9723 |        3 |   1 |         1 |
+---------+----------+-----+-----------+
```

What I need is to update **tickets.win** and **tickets.processed** under rule that all rows in **playedmatches** of the given **playedmatches.ticketid** are processed. If lets say, every match with **ticketid = 2** is **processed = 1** I need to update **tickets.processed** to 1. Further, if all processed matches are **win = 1** then **tickets.win = 1** as well.

In this case, tickets table should like like:

```
+----------+-----+-----------+
| ticketid | win | processed |
+----------+-----+-----------+
|        1 |   0 |         1 |
|        2 |   1 |         1 |
|        3 |   0 |         0 |
+----------+-----+-----------+
```

I have some ideas how to do this with 2 MySQL calls in php but I'm really trying to figure out if it is possible to do with just a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to have it in a single query, you can test something like this:

```
update tickets t join (
    select ticketid, if(sum(win) = count(*), 1, 0) as allwin
    from playedmatches
    group by ticketid
    having sum(processed) = count(*)
) j on j.ticketid = t.ticketid
set t.processed = 1,
    t.win = if(j.allwin, 1, t.win);
```

Comment: Simply beautiful! Would you use this approach over selecting bunch of data and compare it in PHP and then use additional update query? This sounds faster on large set of data. I might be very wrong though.

Comment: If sum = count. Never crossed my mind, this really is beautiful. It feels like I'm learning so much just by looking at this query.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't like to come across a query like this in a production system I maintained. So it depends. If you are doing it with several queries, you need to take into account possible race conditions (use transaction?) between those queries (if that's a concern at all). And if you don't have performance constrains I would probably suggest to express your business logic in a language that is not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a view of `playedmatches` and aggregate over `ticketid` with

```
count(ticketid) as a, sum(win) as b, sum(processed) as c
```

All tickets are processed when a = b. All processed matches are win when a = b = c.

This will give you the information you need to do the two updates via PHP.

Comment: Thanks for idea, I was thinking something around views as well, but I read somewhere that it gets real slow on large data to read view. Can't find source for that, I might be totally wrong.